# how to insert multiple documents in mongodb into a collection using json.parse()

Tags: json, mongodb

i have a json file with these data

```
 {
            'EDUCATION_ID' : 1,
            'CANDIDATE_ID' : 3,
            'EDUCATION_TYPE' : "MTech",
            'INSTITUTE_NAME' : "IIT Kanpur",
            'YEAR_OF_COMPLETION' : 2002,
            'CREATE_DT' : "2008-12-06",
            'UPD_DT' : null,
            'EXPERIENCE' : 8
        },
        {
            'EDUCATION_ID' : 2,
            'CANDIDATE_ID' : 5,
            'EDUCATION_TYPE' : "MBA",
            'INSTITUTE_NAME' : "KIIT Bhubaneshwar",
            'YEAR_OF_COMPLETION' : 2000,
            'CREATE_DT' : "2001-08-14",
            'UPD_DT' : "2004-10-22",
            'EXPERIENCE' : 3
        }
```

I am trying to insert these into mongodb using the following code.Only the first document is getting inserted.can any one explain why?,also can anyone suggest any better way to do read from a external file and insert to db.I am new to mongodb.Any suggestions are gladly accepted :)

```
        MongoClient mc=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        DB db=mc.getDB("mydb");
        String file=ReadAndWrite.func2();//i am reading from a external json file
        DBObject dbo = (DBObject) JSON.parse(file);
        DBCollection dbc=db.getCollection("candidate_education");
        dbc.insert(dbo);
```

Comment: actually your json should start with [ not { (and end with ]) to be treated as array ([{doc1},{doc2}]). try that.

Comment: What language is this? I'm surprised that this code is not bombing out on the `JSON.parse` line, since that is not valid JSON, its two objects separated by a comma.

Comment: Consider using [monogimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to ingest JSON data from a file into MongoDB.

Comment: @Disposer i originally tried that... but it showed parse exception when i surrounded it with a '[]', so i tried it this way.